# TableLayoutPanel in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, tablelayoutpanel

I have the code that generates the textBox therefore can not give properties one by one.
TextBox need you in it can only enter numbers, try the KeyPress but I can not assign it:

I managed to define some properties as follows:

```
  tableLayoutPanel1.Controls [a * size+ b].enabled = false;
  tableLayoutPanel1.Controls [a * size + b]= Color.FromArgb.BackColor (255, 255, 153);
  tableLayoutPanel1.Controls [a + b * size].font = new Font(tableLayoutPanel1.Controls [a + b * size].font, FontStyle.Bold);
```

But a "Global" event for me textBox generated was impossible.
Besides I need the textAlign, I tried as follows:

```
tableLayoutPanel1.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
```

But I do not recognize the "TextAlign".

So they are relatively simple questions but has spent my time trying everything :(

PD: My Event KeyPress is:

```
    private void keyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (((e.KeyChar) < 48 && e.KeyChar != 8) || e.KeyChar > 57)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

But i cant asigned it to the generated textBox, thanks!

Comment: It is not at all clear what you are asking.  The `TableLayoutPanel` does not have text, it is just a container control, so there is no need for a `TextAlign` property

Comment: Yes, but i want "edit" the text inside the textBox when they are created.

Comment: `But a "Global" event for me textBox generated was impossible`  You just have to assign each TextBox's KeyPress event to that keyPress method you wrote.  If need be, inspect the sender parameter to see which TextBox is firing the event.  TableLayoutPanel cell's can only have one parent control in them, and the way you are accessing them via the Controls collection is pretty darn ugly (does your method even work?).  A simple tutorial on the TableLayoutPanel control would help you a great deal.

Comment: The textBox are not created until the user runs the app, I can't "select" TextBox to assign a KeyPress :(

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void Txt_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (((e.KeyChar) < 48 && e.KeyChar != 8) || e.KeyChar > 57)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox txt = new TextBox();
        txt.KeyPress += Txt_KeyPress; // attach event handler to textbox created at runtime.
        tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(txt);
    }
```

If the above code not solving your problem, just comment with explanation. Cheers !

Comment: Did this solve the problem? Please comment your feedback.